# How to end the streaming response to an npm oauth.get request to Twitter stream API?

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, get, streaming

How do I stop the streaming response to this get request? At first I used npm twitter, where you have a .destroy() method to kill streams, but wanted to better understand the process (node newb here) so used only npm oauth, then core Node code. I couldn't find a comparable method to twitter's .destroy() in oauth's documentation.

```
    stream = oauth.get('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?&track=meaningoflife', 
                             process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, 
                             process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    stream.end(); 

    stream.addListener('response', function(twitResponse){ 
         twitResponse.addListener('data', function(data){
             //consume stream here              
         });
    });
```

That works fine, the stream comes in as expected. Closing it is the only issue. 
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer, for anyone having similar issues: Treat stream like a normal Node https/http get request, use [.abort()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_abort) to kill the connection with Twitter. Looks like:

```
    stream.abort();
```

For context/to clarify: I have a front end ajax request trigger the disconnection. Make sure you isolate the abort, if you do use it, to when you know the user (or you, as admin, or however you're managing your stream) wants to disconnect from Twitter. (That was probably obvious; I wanted to state it plainly, if not so -- didn't want you to think the abort should immediately follow the end from the OP code block.)

A word of caution, on the general topic of disconnections from Public Stream API 1.1: Twitter emphasizes that they don't want frequent disconnections/re-connections [(see bottom of this page)](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public). I asked my OP question originally intending to make a customized stream for every user, so if you're looking at this, then there's a chance you're considering the same thing. Unfortunately, Twitter's Public Stream really doesn't support this. Womp womp.